# Not able to match existing route path and getting 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, sammy.js

I have following html markup where the action is one of the route path defined in sammyjs routing code:

```
<form id="loginform" action="#/login" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

<!-- input & hidden elements -->

<!-- submit button -->

</form>
```

if the above view was loaded via url like **"localhost:xxx/Account/Login"**, when I submit the above form, sammyjs logs the error that it is not able to find the route:

```
[Thu Apr 24 2014 13:52:39 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] #shell 404 Not Found get /Account/Login#/login  
Error {message: "404 Not Found get /Account/Login#/login ", stack: "Error↵    at Object.Sammy.Application.$.extend.err…/localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/require.js:132:23"}
message: "404 Not Found get /Account/Login#/login "
stack: "Error↵    at Object.Sammy.Application.$.extend.error (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/sammy-0.7.4.js:1346:47)↵    at Object.Sammy.Application.$.extend.notFound (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/sammy-0.7.4.js:1335:22)↵    at Object.Sammy.Application.$.extend.runRoute (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/sammy-0.7.4.js:1179:21)↵    at Object.Sammy.Application.$.extend._checkLocation (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/sammy-0.7.4.js:1365:25)↵    at Object.Sammy.Application.$.extend.run (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/sammy-0.7.4.js:971:12)↵    at http://localhost:36141/Scripts/App/common.js:36:19↵    at Object.context.execCb (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/require.js:1650:33)↵    at Object.Module.check (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/require.js:866:51)↵    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/require.js:1113:34)↵    at http://localhost:36141/Scripts/Vendor/require.js:132:23"
__proto__: d
```

I'm not able to to understand why does sammy look for **"/Account/Login#/login"** as my form action is set to **"#/login"**.

I have also tried changing my script below for the route path mentioned in error above, like from **"#/login"** to **"/Account/Login#/login"**, but again I get the same error as mentioned in the link above.

```
this.post('#/login', function (context) {
//process
});
```

Same happens with other links or form tags. the hash tag that I want to use get suffixed to whatever is in the url like **"/Account/Login#{/any_hash_tag}"**.
What should I do to solve this?

However, everything works fine if the view was loaded via url like **"localhost:xxx/"** that is with no other route parameters.

It would be great to know if there is something that I'm doing wrong.

Cheers

Comment: You're using relative links... If you were viewing `www.mysite.com/pages/index.html` and there was a link with an href of `about.html`, where would you expect that to take you? `www.mysite.com/about.html` or `www.mysite.com/pages/about.html`?

Comment: @JasonP I'm not writing relative links anywhere. Its sammy routing library that is adding current url + form's action ("#/login") so it becomes "/Account/Login#login".  Even I'm not able to figure out this as I expect sammy routing to look for "#/login" path.

Comment: @Yoda You are __absolutely__ using relative paths. Study up on how URL Fragments work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how [URL Fragments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) work.

Sammy expects the route to begin at the domain name followed by a slash.
Anchor tags linking to `#[anything]` will append that URL fragment to the end of the current view.

You could solve this a couple ways:

1. Use Sammy completely, or don't use it at all.  I'm not sure why you would ever have a route like `/Account/Login#/login`, but it looks messy and it looks like there are two routers. That's no fun.  Use Sammy like `#/account/login`.
2. Make your link action do `/#/login`.  That will reset the base route to the web root, and then append the fragment to the end.

Comment: I was following #2 before with a view with loader but as I changed my default url to "/Account/Login", I started getting this route not found errors. also, looking  in Paths section on http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes, sammy works with relative urls as well.